# OpenCV Adaptive Thresholding in Java

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, ocr, adaptive-threshold

The javadoc mentions signature of adaptive threshold function as

```
adaptiveThreshold(src, dst, maxValue, adaptiveMethod, thresholdType, blockSize, C)
```

I need to somehow put in values for `blockSize` and `C`(offset) automatically given a particular image. So I get a colored image which I convert to gray scale and then apply adaptive threshold as a pre-proccessing step for OCR.

Currently I hardcode the values for `blocksize` and `C` and see what gives me better result and then settle on that value. Is there a way to somehow find the best(or better) values for these parameters so that given a grayscale image my algorithm knows what would be good values for `blocksize` and 'C'.

PS: The adaptive threshold method that I am using is `ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C`.